# Command tr upper and lower extract

Tags: linux, uppercase, lowercase, tr

If I want to convert the text part after the `-` character like
could I do with the `tr` command?

Using this command applies the function on all the text

```
cat file.txt | tr [: upper:] [: lower:]

01103I-GG102
01103I-GG102
01103I-GG102
01103I-GG102
01103I-HH'2
01103I-HH'2
01103I-HH'2
01103I-HH'2
01103I-HH'2
01103I-HH'2
01103I-HH'2
01103I-HH'2
01103I-HH'3
01103I-HH'12
01103I-HH'12
01103I-HH'12
01103I-HH'12
01103I-HH'12
01103I-HH'12
01103I-HH'12
01103I-HH'22
01103I-HH'22
01103I-HH'22
01103I-HH'42
01103I-HH'42
01103I-HH'42
01103I-HH'42
01103I-HH'42
01103I-HH'42
01103I-HH'43
01103I-GG62
01103I-GG62
01103I-GG62
01103I-GG62
01103I-GG62
01103I-GG62
01103I-GG62
01103I-GG62
01103I-GG63
01103I-GG63
01103I-GG63
01103I-GG63
01103I-GG63
01103I-GG63
01103I-GG63
01103I-GG52
```

You can help me?

Thank you

Comment: did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would go for a `sed` solution. The following sed command does transform your input file as requested in your post (to lowercase after the `-`)

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)-\(.*\)/\1-\L\2/g' file
01103I-gg102
01103I-gg102
01103I-gg102
01103I-gg102
01103I-hh'2
01103I-hh'2
01103I-hh'2
01103I-hh'2
01103I-hh'2
01103I-hh'2
01103I-hh'2
01103I-hh'2
01103I-hh'3
01103I-hh'12
01103I-hh'12
01103I-hh'12
01103I-hh'12
01103I-hh'12
01103I-hh'12
01103I-hh'12
01103I-hh'22
01103I-hh'22
01103I-hh'22
01103I-hh'42
01103I-hh'42
01103I-hh'42
01103I-hh'42
01103I-hh'42
01103I-hh'42
01103I-hh'43
01103I-gg62
01103I-gg62
01103I-gg62
01103I-gg62
01103I-gg62
01103I-gg62
01103I-gg62
01103I-gg62
01103I-gg63
01103I-gg63
01103I-gg63
01103I-gg63
01103I-gg63
01103I-gg63
01103I-gg63
01103I-gg52
```

**Explanations:**

- `s/\(.*\)-\(.*\)/\1-\L\2/g` you use sed in replacing mode and capture the 2 groups surrounding the `-`, then you use back reference as replacement and transform to lower case the 2nd group (that contains the pattern after the `-`) using `\L` option.

***`tr`* usage:**

If you are sure that you have only `H` and `G` in the second part of each line and that they do not appear in the fist part then you could imagine something like `tr 'HG...' 'hg...'` but this the maximum this little `tr` command can do.

Answer (score 1):

@Allan's `sed` solution is better, but for the sake of variety, here is another way of doing it.

The part inside the first `<(...)` extracts the part before the dash. The part inside the second `<(...)` extracts the part after the dash and transforms it with `tr`. The `paste` then re-assembles the two parts:

```
paste -d- <(cut -f1 -d- file.txt) <(cut -d- -f2 file.txt | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])
```

Note that this technique is a *"bashism"*, so you would need to be using the `bash` shell.

---

For even more variety, you can do it with `awk` as well:

```
awk -F- '{$2=tolower($2)} 1' OFS=- file.txt
```

Thats says... *"Use dash (`-`) as the field separator. Change the letters in field 2 to lower case. Print the result - because `awk`'s default action is to print if conditions are met, and as `1` evaluates to true, it prints."*

Comment: Nice answer!!! :) :) I will vote up as soon as I will be able to (quota reached...)